# TVP stored procedure taking too long to load than usual

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, table-valued-parameters

Our table valued stored procedures are taking a longer time to load data than usual. Please find the below details:

Number of rows: 1.3M

- Time taken to load (old): 3 min
- Time taken to load (new): 25-40 min.

Nothing has changed in the server. Can you please give me pointers as to what needs to be looked into?

Application: we have deployed a SSIS package in SQL Server, which extracts data from different teradata sources in a loop and creates a datatable and executes a stored procedure using script component

Regards,
Swathi S

Have tried putting the insert within a transaction

```
Insert into (col1, col2....) 
    select col1, col2 
    from @tvpvariable
```

Comment: Do you have a trace running that captures rpc events? That can cause these symptoms if the server is not up to the latest patch level. If the TVP source is a DataTable, make sure the max column length for string columns is set to match the TVP max column size.

Comment: You are loading 1.3M rows into a table valued parameter? And you were ok with 3 minutes? Sounds like you are overdue for performance tuning this process already. Without some details of stuff this is really hard to diagnose.

Comment: @DanGuzman we do not have trace running to capture rpc events. However this database contains replication from 4 databases and a trace for that. But thats been there from a long time

Comment: @SeanLange we are loading 1.3M records from TVP into a table. I have edited m y description

Comment: Are statistics being updated/maintained on this database and/or table/index?

Comment: @FembotDBA we truncate the table and load it everyday. We just have a primary key index.

Comment: Anyway you can transfer the table directly into a staging table, not table valued parameter? TVP are not great for performance. The fastest way to ingest data to SQL Server is bulk copy, which you can do from SSIS. By using a TVP you are shoving all this data into memory and will have to deal with contention with the server activity/memory usage. This posting might help explain more bout why TVP aren't great for performance: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2018/03/table-valued-parameters-unexpected-parameter-sniffing/

Comment: No offense meant but this is like taking a Yugo to an Indy race and wondering how you can make your car fast like the others. This process needs to be examined and probably have large portions gutted and redesigned. The type of performance change you are experiencing is often when the execution plan has to change to support larger numbers of rows. But pumping 1.3M through a TVP is so horribly inefficient that there isn't likely much that can be done.

Comment: @FembotDBA statistics are being updated. And the package is a dynamic loader, extracts from different teradata sources one at a time and uses script component to load into table valued stored procedure

Comment: @SeanLange I will look into other options. but it was taking 3min to load all the data and been taking 3 min from past 4 months and all of a sudden it stared to take more time.